# GET not redirecting the page nodeJS/mongo

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pug

I have a POST that is an ajax post based on a button and the form has it's own post. Every time the button is clicked a post is made but it does not redirect to the userProfile Page even tho it is calling a get for it and returning a 304 for it.

Here is the script file:

```
 $('.removeEmail').click(function() {
        $.post('/removeEmailPost', {userE: $(this).data('user')});
        });
```

Here is the routes file:

```
exports.newEmailPost = function(req, res) {
    if(req.body.emailNew === '') {
        console.log('blank');
        res.redirect('editUserProfile');
    } else {
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.signedCookies.userid,{
            $addToSet: {emailList: req.body.emailNew}
        }, function(err, userX) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);

            } else {

                res.redirect('userProfile');
            }       
            console.log(userX);
        });     
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `type="button"` attribute to your `<button>`, so it doesn't auto-submit the form when clicked.

Comment: Hey sorry yeah I did that it works, but now I am having a different problem... I switched up the question, any clue?

Comment: you shouldn't change your question.. undo your changes and make a new question if you need to